# Restoring Cassandra fails

Tags: cassandra, restore, permission-denied

I try to restore a Cassandra table from snapshot , but when i try to see the result the query give me a `rpc_timeout` so i tried to see the log files

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/cassandra/data/key_space/table/table-ib-2-Data.db (Permission denied)

how i get the snapshot:

> $  nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 snapshot

how i restore the snapshot:

> $ sudo service cassandra stop

in this level i cleared all files from `commitlog`

> $ cp –R   /..../snapshot/..../1379314573738/.   /var/lib/cassandra/data/..../table/
>
> $ sudo service cassandra start

Why this happened and How can i resolve this?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Cassandra doesn't have permission to read the restored sstable. Check the file permissions and ownership.